# Verify element existence in Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I can't figure out how to do this even after looking at the API. I want to scrape data over the web and I have the following code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//path')
```

Now before the find_element part executes. I want to know if the element in fact exists. I've tried the following:

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//path')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print ('failure')
```

*And*

```
if (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//path')[0].size() == 0):
    print ('failure')
```

But neither of them work, even though the API says size() is a callable function of `WebElement` and the exception is throw by the `find` family of methods. I don't understand why neither of those work. What is
the explanation and what would be a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code snippet should raise `NoSuchElementException` if the element is missing. If it does not do that, then it is unclear from the information in your question why that's the case. (Or maybe you *expect* it to not find an element but it *does* find one?)

The 2nd snippet cannot work because the `find_element_...` methods return `WebElement` objects, not lists of objects. You'd have to do:

```
if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//path')) == 0:
    print ('failure')
```

Note the plural `find_elements_...` The functions to find elements that are in the plural return lists, and if they don't find anything the list is of length zero.

By the way, the `size()` method on `WebElement` objects returns the rendered size of the element, that is, its height and width on the page.