# Python: How can I verify that an element on the page has been removed?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a `Clear Filter` button on my `UI` that is removed after being clicked on.

My testcase is as follows:

> 1) Click the Clear Filter button
>
> 2) Check that the Clear Filter button has been removed from the UI

In the code below I am clicking the button and then I try to click it again, because it doesn't exist the test case should pass, but I am trying to verify the failure by attempting to click on it again, this doesn't seem like the best way to go about it...

```
 log_page.clear_filter_bttnclick()

    try:
        if log_page.clear_filter_bttnclick():
            testrailFunctions.failed()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        testrailFunctions.passed()
```

Can I use a `try/except` here to verify the button is removed or is there a better way about going about confirming that the `Clear Filter` button no longer exists on the `UI`?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Selenium WebDriver - Checking element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/python-selenium-webdriver-checking-element-exists)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is present or not.

In python it should done something like below :-

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

Source :-

[Python - Selenium WebDriver - Checking element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/python-selenium-webdriver-checking-element-exists)

OR

methods return WebElement objects, not lists of objects. You'd have to do:

```
if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//path')) == 0:
    print ('element not present')
```

Sorce :-

[verify element existence selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452749/verify-element-existence-selenium)